# Wordpress Dashboard Display error

Tags: php, jquery, css, wordpress

I have a huge problem with my wordpress dashboard display. After I upgrade to wordpress 4.5 my dashboard gone crazy.... its seems like it is not displaying css correctly. Its really killing me cause I could not write any article ...which very bad for my website. My dashboard looks like:

[image]

This is what seems to be the problem:

[image]

I tried everything. First I thought that is might be chrome's problem. I deleted history/cache ...etc. Not working. Then I deleted chrome and reinstalled it. Not worked. Then I used firefox, opera,internet explorer ... not worked. I put one friend of mine to look... it seems also the same to him. Then, I deleted wordpress 4.5 core file (wp-admin, wp-include) from ftp and installed back wordpress 4.4.2 and it looks the same..... I'm really desperate. I sought help on wordpress official website.... nobody helped me.... its crucial for me to solve this problem I really live with site's help. I really don't have any idea to solve it. This is killing me :(.

I appreciate any help.....

Comment: Add below code in `wp-config.php` file.
`define('CONCATENATE_SCRIPTS', false );`

Comment: Can you check the Network tab to make sure the CSS files actually loaded? Also try enabling debug mode in wp-config

Comment: @milap I added that code in wp config .... there's an improvment but the problem not solved. screenshot: http://i.imgur.com/1H31PIt.png <br/> aziz I enabled debug mode in config ... also not solved the problem :(

Comment: Hmm, so now it's loading the icon font, but still not the rest of the CSS.

Answer (score 2):

Add below code in `wp-config.php` file of your WordPress.

`define('CONCATENATE_SCRIPTS', false );`

It should solve your problem, you can read more details on below link.

http://manovotny.com/fix-wordpress-admin-styles-not-loading/

Comment: adding define('CONCATENATE_SCRIPTS', false );
define('SCRIPT_DEBUG', true ); results in many other errors: http://i.imgur.com/uNplTjO.png

Comment: Can anyone explain why this works? I'd like to understand this.

Answer (score 1):

`jQuery is not defined` errors usually indicate that jQuery hasn't been loaded at all, so then other scripts that depend on jQuery being present throw the error.

Where are you loading jQuery from? [According to this issue](https://discourse.roots.io/t/soil-google-hosted-jquery-errors-wordpress-4-5/6460) someone had a problem where they were including jQuery from Google's CDN, and WordPress was trying to load a version of jQuery that wasn't present in Google's CDN.

A link to your site would be helpful - it's difficult to determine what all is going on from only that screenshot.

Comment: http://www.cosmosup.com/    ..... So what I tried so far: I used define('CONCATENATE_SCRIPTS', false ); Then I renamed all needed css file in the wp-admin/css by adding the "min" in the name. This worked! But this mean that I will never could upload on the upcoming wordpress versions :( an thus also my plugins.

Comment: You're right, that's not ideal. I'm curious: which prior version of WordPress did you upgrade from?

Comment: 4.4.2 I hadn't problem with it .... I solved the problem partially as I wrote up, but its not ideal as you say ... but I have no choice ... I need to put my blog on its feet.... Thanks you for your replay !!!!

Comment: Sorry I couldn't be more helpful.

Answer (score 1):

It also looks like your site isn't loading any of the CSS for the admin area. Have you doublechecked your `WordPress address` and `Site Address` options in the admin?

[image]

This might also be set in your `wp-config.php` file:

```
define('WP_HOME','http://example.com');
define('WP_SITEURL','http://example.com');
```

If your `WordPress Address` (which is the same as `WP_HOME`) setting doesn't match the URL with which you're trying to access the WP admin area, then you'll see symptoms like your site is exhibiting, where CSS doesn't load properly and some javascript may be missing.

Answer (score 1):

One more suggestion: try activating a different theme temporarily (such as Twenty Fifteen) and see if that fixes up the WP admin. You may have a conflict specific to your current theme package.

Comment: I actually tried ... If I did try almost everything, as I said, ....I even put some friend of mine to check. Your were my last hope, and you helped me.... For this I thank you all ..... I solved the problem partially as I said up, not ideal but its necessary.

Answer (score 0):

Take care of adding `define( 'CONCATENATE_SCRIPTS', false );` at the top of declarations, after comments.

Comment: this response is already suggested in another answer. it might help if you explain more here: how or why.